# PHP form sendeail.php not identifying new form items

Tags: php, html, forms

I am trying to add new items to a legacy sendeail.php form. However, when I add the new items to the php listing and the mail delivery, they aren't displaying at all in the email that is sent. At least the emails are going through... I know that I need to refine the radio and check box items, but NONE of the new items are showing. New items are all items after $attn in the code list immediately below. Any and all help is appreciated, thank you very much!

My PHP code is:

```
<?php

$ip = $_POST['ip']; 
$httpref = $_POST['httpref']; 
$httpagent = $_POST['httpagent']; 
$visitor = $_POST['visitor']; 
$visitormail = $_POST['visitormail']; 
$notes = $_POST['notes'];
$attn = $_POST['attn'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$interest = $_POST['interest'];
$budget = $_POST['budget'];
$budget = $_POST['day'];
$timeslot = $_POST['timeslot'];

if (eregi('http:', $notes)) {
die ("Do NOT try that! ! ");
}
if(!$visitormail == "" && (!strstr($visitormail,"@") || !strstr($visitormail,"."))) 
{
echo "<h2>Use Back - Enter valid e-mail</h2>\n"; 
$badinput = "<h2>Please complete all the fields.</h2>\n";
echo $badinput;
die ("Use the Back button on your browser...");
}

if(empty($visitor) || empty($visitormail) || empty($notes )  || empty($attn )  || empty($phone )) {
echo "<h2>Please click Back and fill in all fields.</h2>\n";
die ("Use the Back button on your browser... "); 
}

$todayis = date("l, F j, Y, g:i a") ;

$attn = $attn ; 
$subject = $attn; 

$notes = stripcslashes($notes); 

$message = " $todayis [EST] \n
Web Site Request About: $attn \n
From: $visitor ($visitormail)\n
Phone: $phone \n
Message: $notes \n 
Interested In: $interest \n
Heating Budget: $budget \n
Time Availability: Days - $day \n
Time Availability: Morning or Afternoon - $timeslot \n


Additional Info : IP = $ip \n
Browser Info: $httpagent \n
Referral : $httpref \n
";

$from = "From: $visitormail\r\n";


mail("XXXXX", $subject, $message, $from);

?>
```

And my HTML code is:

```
<?php
$ipi = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");
$httprefi = getenv ("HTTP_REFERER");
$httpagenti = getenv ("HTTP_USER_AGENT");
?>
        <input type="hidden" name="ip" value="<?php echo $ipi ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="httpref" value="<?php echo $httprefi ?>" />
        <input type="hidden" name="httpagent" value="<?php echo $httpagenti ?>" />
        All fields are required.</p>
      <p align="left">Your Name:
        <input type="text" name="visitor" size="35" />
        </p>
      <p align="left">
        Your Email:  
          <input type="text" name="visitormail" size="35" />
        </p>
      <p align="left">
        <label for="Phone">Your Phone: </label>
        <input type="text" name="Phone" id="Phone" size="35"/>
      </span></p>
      <p align="left">
        About:
        <select name="attn" size="1">

select name="interest" id="interest">
          <option value="General Query">General question</option>
          <option value="Plumbing Query">Plumbing</option>
          <option value="Gasfitting Query">Gasfitting</option>
          <option value="Central Heating Query">Central Heating</option>
          <option value="Custom Work Query">Several options</option>
          </select>
        <br />

  <p align="left">Your Home Heating Budget:

    <select name="attn2" size="1">


select name="budget" id="budget">
      <option value="Under 10000">$8000 to $10,0000</option>
      <option value="10 to 12 Thousand">$10,000 to $12,000</option>
      <option value="12 to 15 Thousand">$12,000 to $15,000</option>
      <option value="+15000 Plus">$15,000 +</option>
      </select>
    <br />
    <p align="left">Are you considering other forms of heating? 
    <input type="checkbox" name="Yes-OtherFormsHeating" id="Yes-OtherFormsHeating" />
    <label for="Yes">Yes</label>
     <input type="checkbox" name="No-OtherFormsHeating" id="No-OtherFormsHeating" />
    <label for="No">No</label>
    <br />
    </p>
    <p align="left">Please give us a few details about your home and requirements: <br />
      <textarea name="notes" rows="6" cols="70"></textarea>
    </p>


    <p align="left">To give you a quote for gas central heating, we need to visit your home. What is a good day and time for us to come to you? Choose one option.</p>
    <p align="left">
      <input type="radio" name="day" id="day_M" value="M" />
      <label for="M">M</label>
      <input type="radio" name="day" id="day_T" value="T" />
      <label for="T">T</label>
      <input type="radio" name="day" id="day-W" value="W" />
      <label for="W">W</label>
      <input type="radio" name="day" id="day_Th" value="Th" />
      <label for="Th">Th</label>
      <input type="radio" name="day" id="day_F" value="F" />
      <label for="F">F</label>
    </p>
    <p align="left">When is a good time on this day for us to come to you? Choose one or both.</p>
    <p align="left">
      <input type="checkbox" name="timeslot" id="8:30-12:30AM" />
      <label for="8:30-12:30AM">8:30 - 12:30</label>
      <input type="checkbox" name="timeslot" id="12:30-4" />
      <label for="12:30-4">12:30 - 4:00</label>
    </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all: **always validate input** (`POST`). You've got some basic validation already but read up on the security implications regarding `POST` data.

Array keys in php are case sensitive. `$_POST['phone']` is not the same as `$_POST['Phone']`.

Your `select` tags are broken, take a look at the colouring in your posted `html`.

You have declared `$budget` twice, overwriting the intended data:

```
$budget = $_POST['budget'];
$budget = $_POST['day'];
```

`checkboxes` should be arrays when posted, change the `name` attribute to `thename[]` instead of just `thename`. Of course your php script must handle the resulting array after this change.